# Indexing and doing mathematical calculation with Numpy Arrays Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, indexing

The code below calculates the `Compounding` values starting from 100 and the percentage gains `gains`. I want to write a code that goes start off with the entirety of the gains array `[20,3,4,55,6.5]` resulting in `212.19` at the end and then takes off the first index and recalculates the compounding value `[3,4,55,6.5]` resulting in `176.82`., It would do this until the end of the gains array `[6.5]`. how would I be able to implement this to the code below and get the expected output?

```
import numpy as np 
Amount = 100

def moneyrisk(array):
    for counter,iterator in enumerate(array):
        Compounding = Amount * np.cumprod(array / 100 + 1)
    return Compounding

gains= np.array([20,3,4,55,6.5])
print(moneyrisk(gains))
```

Expected output:

```
[212.194008, 176.82834, 171.678, 165.075, 106.5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat the array to make a squared matrix, then remove the lower triangle, apply your function on each row. And, finally extract the last column:

Your `moneyrisk` function is given by:

```
>>> f = lambda x: 100*np.cumprod(x/100 + 1, 1) # notice the axis=1 option
```

Repeat rows:

```
>>> rep = gains[None].repeat(len(gains), 0)
array([[20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5]])
```

Use [`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html?highlight=triu#numpy.triu) to remove the lower triangle:

```
>>> rep_t = np.triu(rep, k=0)
array([[20. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [ 0. ,  3. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  4. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , 55. ,  6.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  6.5]])
```

Apply `f` and select the last column:

```
>>> f(rep_t)
array([[120.      , 123.6     , 128.544   , 199.2432  , 212.194008],
       [100.      , 103.      , 107.12    , 166.036   , 176.82834 ],
       [100.      , 100.      , 104.      , 161.2     , 171.678   ],
       [100.      , 100.      , 100.      , 155.      , 165.075   ],
       [100.      , 100.      , 100.      , 100.      , 106.5     ]])

>>> f(rep_t)[:, -1]
array([212.194008, 176.82834 , 171.678   , 165.075   , 106.5     ])
```

Comment: Hi I have another question that is related to this. I want to get the minimum value in compounding calculations and see if it is below the capital `Amount` if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612619/getting-the-minimum-value-by-using-lambda-through-numpy-array-python