# Getting the minimum value by using lambda through numpy Array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, lambda

The code below calculates the `Compounding` values starting from $100 and the percentage gains `gains`. The code below goes from the start off with the entirety of the gains array `[20,3,4,55,6.5,-10, 20,-60,5]` resulting in `96.25` at the end and then takes off the first index and recalculates the compounding value `[3,4,55,6.5,-10, 20,-60,5]` resulting in `80.20`. It would do this until the end of the gains array `[5]`. I want to write a code that calculates maximum drawdown as it is calculating `f`. This would be the compounding results for the first iteration of `f` `[120., 123.6 ,128.544, 199.243, 212.194008 190.9746072, 229.16952864, 91.66781146, 96.25120203]` I want to record a value if it is lower than the initial capital `Amount` value. So the lowest value is `91.67` on the first iteration so that would be the output, and on the second iteration it would be `76.37`. Since in the last iteration there is `[5]` which results in the compounding output of `105` there are no values that go below 100 so it is `None` as the output. How would I be able to implement this to the code below and get the expected output?

```
import numpy as np 

Amount = 100
def moneyrisk(array):
    
    f = lambda array: Amount*np.cumprod(array/100 + 1, 1) 
    rep = array[None].repeat(len(array), 0)
    rep_t = np.triu(rep, k=0)
    final = f(rep_t)[:, -1]
  
gains= np.array([20,3,4,55,6.5,-10, 20,-60,5])
```

Expected output:

```
[91.67, 76.37, 74.164, 71.312, 46.008, 43.2, 48., 40., None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've understood the requirement.  Calculating the compound factors after the `np.triu` fills the zeroes with ones which means the `min` method returns a valid value.

```
import numpy as np  

gains= np.array( [20,3,4,55,6.5,-10, 20,-60,5] ) # Gains in %
amount = 100

def moneyrisk( arr ):
    rep = arr[ None ].repeat( len(arr), 0 )
    rep_t = np.triu( rep, k = 0 )
    rep_t = ( 1 + rep_t * .01 )   # Create factors to compound in rep_t 

    result =  amount*(rep_t.cumprod( axis = 1 ).min( axis = 1 ))  
    # compound and find min value.

    return [ x if x < amount else None for x in result ]          
    # Set >= amount to None in a list as numpy floats can't hold None
    
moneyrisk( gains )

# [91.667811456, 76.38984288, 74.164896, 71.3124, 46.008, 43.2, 48.0, 40.0, None]
```

Comment: Thank you it works is there a way I could return the last index of each iteration in `result` possibly and get values like this `96.25120203, 80.20933502, 77.8731408, 74.87802, 48.3084 ,45.36, 50.4, 42, 105`

Comment: `result[:, -1]]`, the last column of result.